# centering content of first row in a tabularx include hyphenation

Tags: tabularx

I want the **first** row in a `tabularx` to be the headlines. So the content of the first row should be *centered*, *bold* and with *hyphenation*.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \centering\textbf{A}&
    \textbf{B head centered with hyphenation please}\\
    \hline
    a&b\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

When I use `centering` for the second column head I get a *missplaced align* error message.

I know a workaround with `\multicolumn{1}{c}` or `\thead`. But both of them deactivte hyphenation.

Comment: Use `\tabularnewline` instead of ``\\``, because `\centering` modifies the meaning of ``\\``; this has no consequence in the first column, but of course can't work in the final one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you load the `ragged2e` package as well and define a new column type (after loading `tabularx`) via the instruction

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

Then, use the instruction

```
\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{|X|C|}
```

to define the table's structure.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} % since the MWE is in English...

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{|X|C|}
    \hline
    \centering\textbf{A}&
    \textbf{B head centered with hyphenation please}\\
    \hline
    a&b\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment and clarification: If only a cell but not the remaining entries in a column  should be centered, use a `\multicolumn` "wrapper" to override the column type for the cell in question. In the code below, the `C` column type is defined as above, viz., `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}`.

```
...
\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{|X|X|}
\hline
\centering\textbf{A} 
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{\textbf{B head centered with hyphenation please}}\\
\hline
a&b\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
...
```

Comment: This centers the whole column. But I only want to center the cells of the **first** row because this should be headlines.

Comment: Does hyphenation work in your `multicolumn`?

Comment: @buhtz - Yes it does. :-) The `\Centering` directive that's part of the definition of the `C` column type allows hyphenation.

Comment: Ah! It is a uppdercase `C` there. It is from `ragged2e`.