# Trying to center the contents of only 1st row cells

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326922/centering-content-of-first-row-in-a-tabularx-include-hyphenation) question but not sure if mine is exactly the same???

I am trying to center just the first row of cells in `tabularx` environment, leaving the rest left/justified.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \centering \textbf{a} & \centering \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} \\
        \hline
        a & b & c \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

When I add `\centering` to the last cell in the 1st row, it throws

> Misplaced \noalign. \end{tabularx}

I know I can circumvent that by adding `$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$` in front of the cell content to approximately center it, but it's ugly.

Comment: try `\centering \textbf{a} & \centering \textbf{b} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{c} ` but better is use `multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` environment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\centering` redefines `\\`, thus it won't no longer work as end of line in a `tabular`. But there is `\tabularnewline`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \centering \textbf{a} & \centering \textbf{b} & \centering \textbf{c}
        \tabularnewline
        \hline
        a & b & c \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]